# Can I set bricks with mortar on a new concrete stoop before it cures?

Tags: concrete, brick

I'm pouring a new stoop, and I'd like to finish the corners with a brick that's used elsewhere on the house, so everything ties in.

I'm planning on pouring the stoop with a channel for the brick, so it looks like

```
      _______ 
 ____|       |____
|                 |
```

Instead of

```
 _________________
|                 |
```

I was wondering if I can strip the form after a couple hours and set the brick with mortar while the concrete is still curing or if I need to wait a few days for the concrete to cure.

Again, nothing structural here, just wanting to adhere the brick to the stoop.

Comment: Oh come on, the asterisks were so much better.

Comment: @AlaskaMan lol cut me a break, I'm on my phone haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, as long as the concrete will support the weight. A few hours in it'll still be very fragile, especially if your weather is cool. You'll have to feel it out and make a judgement call. Plenty of times we've built basement walls on a new slab the next morning. If we're talking about a single row of brick it should be fine.

Concrete shrinks very slightly as it cures, but I doubt that'll be an issue for you here.

Comment: My principal concern would be tool-marks while removing the form.

Comment: With most stoops the surface is worked after form removal anyway.

Comment: @ShapeOfMatter - like what Isherwood said, the advice I had seen online was to hold back some concrete and strip the form while the concrete was firm but still workable, so some of the concrete held in reserve can be used to patch any voids, etc.